# Naming exported features from attribute information?

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer, error-000210

I am new to Python and in the process of learning. As a self test I am trying to export all of the municipalities of a single county feature layer as their own feature layers. I am trying to name each feature layer based on the municipality label column but Python returns this error "ERROR 000210: Cannot create output" on the last line which is the CopyFeatures_management tool. How can I achieve my desired result?

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\gis\python_training\municipality iteration test\mun test.gdb"
mun = "Municipality"
dict = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mun,["OBJECTID", "MUN_LABEL"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        dict[row[0]] = row[1]
del cursor
dict2 = {}
for key, value in dict.items():
    if value not in dict2.values():
        dict2[key] = value
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(mun,"munlyr")
for key in dict2:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("munlyr", "NEW_SELECTION","OBJECTID = " + str(key))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("munlyr", str(value))
```

Comment: The `value` variable is not modified inside your final loop.  BTW: You don't neet to `del` something in a `with`

Comment: And one municipality can be more than one record/feature/row?

Comment: Each municipality is a single row within the initial county layer.

Comment: If so you dont need to use dictionaries. Use the da.SearchCursor with the OID field and municipality field. For each row [Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) using OID field = row[0]

Answer (score 2):

If each row is one municipality (no duplicate rows) you dont need to use dictionaries. Use the da.SearchCursor to iterate over each record, and Select to export to new feature classes:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\gis\python_training\municipality iteration test\mun test.gdb"
mun = "Municipality"

oidfieldname = arcpy.Describe(mun).OIDFieldName
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mun,[oidfieldname,"MUN_LABEL"]) as cursor:
    for oid, munlabel in cursor:
        sql = "{0}={1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=mun,field=oidfieldname),oid)
        arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features=mun, out_feature_class=munlabel, where_clause=sql)
```

(The same results can be achieved by using Split By Attributes tool)